# Detecting wallpaper type

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, android-wallpaper

Is there any way to detect whether live wallpaper or static wallpaper is currently set on the homescreen. I would like to do certain operation based on these condition.

I've have already checked on the internet but couldn't find any solution. So any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`WallpaperManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) to your rescue!!

It has a [`getWallpaperInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#getWallpaperInfo()) that:

> If the current wallpaper is a live wallpaper component, return the
>   information about that wallpaper. Otherwise, if it is a static image,
>   simply return null.

Code snippet:

```
WallpaperManager mgr = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MyActivity.this);
if( mgr.getWallpaperInfo() == null ){
    // static wallpaper
}else{
    // live wallpaper
}
```

Comment: Wow! works like a charm. I've been looking for this. Thank you sooooooooo much for the help :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Have fun developing your app!